# ul li menu - make li:s fill entire ul?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Example: `http://83.254.82.145:8080/android/`

If you hover the map you'll see a menu:

```
<div id="map_menu" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
        <li style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="fitmarkersonmap" style="color: rgb(248, 248, 248);">Fit markers on map</a>
        </li>
        <li style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="togglemaptypes" style="color: rgb(248, 248, 248);">Toggle map types</a>
        </li>
        <li style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="showpopup" style="color: rgb(248, 248, 248);" class="">Show userlist</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Current css:

```
#map_menu ul li {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

If you increase the padding to `0 67px` you will understand what im after. Is there any way to make a dynamic solution to this, without using javascript? I simply want the li:s to fill up the entire ul, without measuring myself each time i add a menu item.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try adding width:100%?

Comment: @AshwinSingh on each li? They would end up on several rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#map_menu ul li {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 33%; /* here is the ratio depends on how much <li> you have */
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center; /* this makes text in the center of <li> */
}

#map_menu ul li:last-child {
  width: 34%;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, but the li:s end up slightly too big

Comment: I suppose the problem is that 800px is not divideable by 3. Otherwise this would work, so ill accept this. Thanks

Comment: @Johan add this line to this solution: `#map_menu ul li:last-child{width:34%;}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the elements to automagically fill the entire container's width *and* no Javascript, `<table>` is there for you. Otherwise there's no way to achieve a 100% width while at the same time keeping the width of each element flexible.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Guess ill have to go for a jquery solution then. I dont like using tables for menus

Answer (score 0):

You could try using CSS display table properties.